# How create List object for class variables using php

Tags: php, yii

in c# we have option to create list object for class variables in the following method,

```
 public class Distribute
    {

        public string Alias { get; set; }
        public string Count { get; set; }

   }

    public List<Distribute> States { get; set; }
```

So my question is , how to implement above code in php using yii framework?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most of the syntax employed in this code snippet is not available in PHP. Instead of asking how to translate a very specific piece of code into another language where that's not applicable, you should ask how to solve the same problem idiomatically in the new language.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use [`SplDoublyLinkedList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.spldoublylinkedlist.php) class or [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface and then override the element set methods (`push` / `offsetSet`)

```
class ListContainer extends SplDoublyLinkedList
{
    protected $type;

    public function __construct($listType)
    {
        $this->type = $listType;
    }

    public function push($value)
    {
        if (!$value instanceof $this->type) {
            throw new Exception('Element must be instance of ' . $this->type);
        }

        parent::push($value);
    }

    public function offsetSet($index , $value)
    {
        if (!$value instanceof $this->type) {
            throw new Exception('Element must be instance of ' . $this->type);
        }

        parent::offsetSet($index, $value);
    }
}

class Distribute
{
    public $alias;
    public $count;
}

$states = new ListContainer('Distribute');
$dist   = new Distribute;
$dist->alias = 'd1';
$dist->count = 17;

$states->push($dist);
```

Comment: It needs to be `!($value instanceof Distribute)`.

Comment: @deceze 1) syntax are both correct, you can try. 2) to give a Exception instead of fatal error.

Comment: Hmm, I'll take it back. Then even the manual gets it needlessly wrong by recommending `!(...)`.

Comment: Yes, because `instanceof` has higher operator precedence than `!`

Comment: Your answer was partially helpful. But not effective in the following scenario,
1) Due to neccessity If I try to create 10 list object for the same class. It consumes more amount of code. Could you please suggest some more optimized answer  @deceze

Comment: @Rocky can u check it again?